# R Shiny: How to pass reactive variables between nested modules

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a toy example in which a textInput() box pops up for the user to input any string, and by clicking the add button, a selectInput() box pops up with the letters a:d prepended with the string.  In other words, if the user inputs "1", then by clicking the "add" button, a selectInput() box pops up with 1a, 1b, 1c, and 1d as choices.  I am using a module for the add/remove button functionality, and that module calls another module to generate the selectInput() box.  The main server function calls the add/remove module, which calls the "first" module, which generates the selectInput() box.  I pass a() as a reactive element to add/remove module, which in turn passes this on to "first" module.  I just used "..." in the function signature of both the add/remove module and the "first" module to get a() to the nested module.

This seems to work, although a() seems to not be reactive by the time it gets to "first" module, meaning that if I type a different string in the "a" box, I would expect that the choices in the selectInput() box to change dynamically, or at least when I change the textInput() string and click "add", the new selectInput() should reflect the updated textInput() string, but this does not happen.  What will make the selectInput() choices change dynamically with changes to textInput()?  Code below, thanks!

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "first")) }

firstServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {

    output$first <- renderUI({
        selectInput(session$ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0(a,letters[1:4]))
    })
}

removeFirstUI <- function(id) {
    removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "first")))
}

addRmBtnUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    tags$div(
    actionButton(inputId = ns('insertParamBtn'), label = "Add"),
    actionButton(ns('removeParamBtn'), label = "Remove"),
    hr(),
    tags$div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

addRmBtnServer <- function(input, output, session, moduleToReplicate,...) {
    ns = session$ns

    params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)

    observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
        params$btn <- params$btn + 1

        callModule(moduleToReplicate$server, id = params$btn, ...)
        insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = moduleToReplicate$ui(ns(params$btn))
    )
    })

    observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
        moduleToReplicate$remover(ns(params$btn))
        params$btn <- params$btn - 1
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
          addRmBtnUI("addRm"),
          textInput("a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px') )

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    a <- reactive({ input$a })
    callModule(
    addRmBtnServer, id = "addRm",
    moduleToReplicate = list(
      ui = firstUI,
      server = firstServer,
      remover = removeFirstUI
    ), a = a()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Assuming i've inferred correctly here, @Sean does my approach solve your purpose ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have

```
a <- reactive({input$a})
```

you need to pass `a` down to the inner (first) module, not `a()`. That is because `a()` represents the *current* value of the observable object `a`. This means `a()` is *not observable*. In your code, `a()` is evaluated in the server scope during startup. At that time, `a` has the value `1` (the default value defined in the corresponding `textInput`) and you pass it as a *static* object.

You can learn more about reactive values [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "first")) }

firstServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {

  output$first <- renderUI({
    selectInput(session$ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0(isolate(a()),letters[1:4]))
  })
}

removeFirstUI <- function(id) {
  removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "first")))
}

addRmBtnUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tags$div(
    actionButton(inputId = ns('insertParamBtn'), label = "Add"),
    actionButton(ns('removeParamBtn'), label = "Remove"),
    hr(),
    tags$div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

addRmBtnServer <- function(input, output, session, moduleToReplicate,...) {
  ns = session$ns

  params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)

  observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
    params$btn <- params$btn + 1

    callModule(moduleToReplicate$server, id = params$btn, ...)
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = moduleToReplicate$ui(ns(params$btn))
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
    moduleToReplicate$remover(ns(params$btn))
    params$btn <- params$btn - 1
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  addRmBtnUI("addRm"),
  textInput("a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px') )

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  a <- reactive({ input$a })
  callModule(
    addRmBtnServer, id = "addRm",
    moduleToReplicate = list(
      ui = firstUI,
      server = firstServer,
      remover = removeFirstUI
    ), 
    a = a
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks again!  Now if I want to wrap firstUI() element in a tags$div (for example, if I want to add and remove several elements in one "chunk", how do I adjust removeFirstUI()?  Ie, if firstUI() is as follows:

Comment: firstUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    tags$div(
        fluidRow(uiOutput(NS(id, "first"))),
        id = paste0('firstui', id)
  )
}

Comment: In this case, I do not want to just remove the UI element "first", but everything in the tags$div(), which could be build to any number of UI elements.  Note the id of fthe tags$div is  id = paste0('firstui', id).  It is the namespacing of the tags$div() id within the module that is tripping me up.  Thanks!

Comment: Use `id = ns('firstui')` and remove the `div` with `removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "firstui")))`. I didn't test it but something like this should do the job.

Comment: Notice that `NS(id,'fitstui')` is equivalent to `ns <- NS(id); ns('firstui')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [example here](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/111-insert-ui/), i've tweaked a little for the desired output.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  actionButton('insertBtn', 'Insert'), 
  actionButton('removeBtn', 'Remove'), 
  tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
  textInput(inputId = "a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ## keep track of elements inserted and not yet removed
  inserted <- c()

  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {
    btn <- input$a
    id <- paste0('txt', btn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = tags$div(
        selectInput(inputId = btn,label = btn,choices = paste(btn,letters[1:4])), 
        id = id
      )
    )
    inserted <<- c(id, inserted)
  })

  observeEvent(input$removeBtn, {
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This results in app like :
[image: snap1]

As observed, the `selectInput`s are added based on `a`.

Comment: Thank you, but I  need to keep it in the modular form that I posted it in.  My actual app is far more complex,  I simplified it for this post.  The point is for me to be able to take a reactive element and pass it as a parameter to a module that creates the add/remove buttons, and then calls a nested module to process that information, in this case with a selectInput() box.  I want to modularize the add/remove buttons so I can easily call them multiple times for different nested modules without having one monolithic and unmaintainable hairball.