# R Shiny: How to pass reactive filtered dataframe between modules

Tags: r, shiny, module

I have a large shiny app working with modules, but I think I am not maximizing the module architecture as I'm failing to pass reactive values between modules.

Below is an MRE that has two separate controls that build separate tables and plots. For the controls, secondary options (v2) get updated upon selection of primary options (v1). For the plots/tables, I am filtering global data at the moment tables/plots get created. I would like to "modularize" this filtered data and make it a reactive object that can be passed to the table and plot server modules.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011116/using-reactive-values-within-r-shiny-modules) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578703/r-shiny-how-to-pass-reactive-variables-between-nested-modules) and [Shiny's example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html), but haven't been able to make it work.

The piece I want to modularize is the following, as it's repeated at the plot and table server modules.

```
mdf <- reactive({
        df %>%
          filter(v1 == input$radio1,
                 v2 == input$radio2)
      })
```

The working MRE

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3)),
                 v2 = c(rep("X",2), rep("Y",2), rep("Z",2)),
                 v3 = 1:6)

mod_controls_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    radioButtons(inputId = ns("radio1"),
                 label = "v1 options",
                 choices = unique(df$v1)),
    radioButtons(inputId = ns("radio2"),
                 label = "contextual v2 options",
                 choices = unique(df$v2))
  )
}
mod_control_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      observeEvent(input$radio1, {
        df = df[df$v1 == input$radio1, ]
        updateRadioButtons(session,
                           inputId = "radio2",
                           choices = unique(df$v2)
        )
      })
      
    })
}
mod_table_ui <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  tableOutput(ns("minitable"))
}
mod_plot_ui <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("miniplot"))
}
mod_plot_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    module = function(input, output, session) {
      mdf <- reactive({
        df %>%
          filter(v1 == input$radio1,
                 v2 == input$radio2)
      })
      output$miniplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mdf(), aes(v1, v3)) +
          geom_point()  
      })
    }
  )
}
mod_table_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    module = function(input, output, session) {
      mdf <- reactive({
        df %>%
          filter(v1 == input$radio1,
                 v2 == input$radio2)
      })
      output$minitable <- renderTable({
        mdf()
      })
    }
  )
}


# APP
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           mod_controls_ui("tbl")),
    column(width = 3,
           mod_table_ui("tbl")),
    column(width = 3,
           mod_plot_ui("plt")),
    column(width = 3,
           mod_controls_ui("plt")),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_control_server("tbl")
  mod_table_server("tbl")
  
  mod_control_server("plt")
  mod_plot_server("plt")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried to return the filtered reactive "mdf" in the `mod_control_server()` and then capture and pass that return to the table/plot server modules, but the output did not update on change of radio buttons. I feel there's an easy way to do this that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a much simpler solution, no need for extra functions. The key was to make the filtered dataframe reactive when responding to input change, and then make the output of the function that returns this value also reactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3)),
                 v2 = c(rep("X",2), rep("Y",2), rep("Z",2)),
                 v3 = 1:6)

mod_controls_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    radioButtons(inputId = ns("radio1"),
                 label = "v1 options",
                 choices = unique(df$v1)),
    radioButtons(inputId = ns("radio2"),
                 label = "contextual v2 options",
                 choices = unique(df$v2))
  )
}
mod_control_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$radio1, {
      df = df[df$v1 == input$radio1, ]
      updateRadioButtons(session,
                         inputId = "radio2",
                         choices = unique(df$v2)
      )
    })
    reactive(df[df$v1 == input$radio1 &
                df$v2 == input$radio2, ])
  })
}
mod_table_ui <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  tableOutput(ns("minitable"))
}
mod_plot_ui <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("miniplot"))
}
mod_plot_server <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      output$miniplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data(), aes(v1, v3)) +
          geom_point()  
      })
  })
}
mod_table_server <- function(id, data) {
 moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
     output$minitable <- renderTable({
       data()
     })
 })
}

# APP
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3, mod_controls_ui("control_tbl")),
    column(width = 3, mod_table_ui("tbl")),
    column(width = 3, mod_plot_ui("plt")),
    column(width = 3, mod_controls_ui("control_plt")),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Tdata <- reactive(mod_control_server("control_tbl"))
  mod_table_server("tbl", Tdata())
  
  Pdata <- reactive(mod_control_server("control_plt"))
  mod_plot_server("plt", Pdata())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```